# Highest Margin product with minimal risk.

Tags: probability

Assume the following scenario.

I can

```
Sell P1 for a profit of  14% 
or sell it at a Loss of -7%

Sell P2 for a profit of 11%
Or sell it at a loss of -6%

Sell P3 for a profit of 7%
or sell for a loss of -1%

Sell P4 for a Profit of 40%
Or sell it at max loss of 35%

Sell P5 for a profit of 40% 
or sell P5 for a loss at 3%
```

Considering the profit margins provided above and max loss rate, at which they need to be cleared by the end of the period.

As a seller, stocking which of the above is more profitable to the business? Assuming all products will be sold at the mentioned P/L levels at the end of the period, with some rare exceptions.

If I consider PL ratio,

```
For P1, it would be 14:7 ~ 2 : 1
For P2, it would be 11:6 ~ 1.9 : 1
For P3, it would be 7:1 ~ 7 : 1
For P4, it would be 40:35 ~ 8:7
For P5, its 40:3 ~ 13.3:1
```

Clearly the higher ratios won't aid in determining the ideal product.

How could I identify the right product?
The product selection should optimize the gains and minimize the losses. So, for a unit of risk, the maximum profit product must be stocked.

Comment: What do you mean by PL ratio?

Comment: Its termed as Profit to Loss Ratio. it is used in businesses. It defines the amount of profit that you could make to the loss you might incur. The ratio must be balanced. Extreme Profit optimisation will often lead to extreme losses. To ensure no such thing happens, the loss part of the equation is used to balance out the risk.